# How interaction terms are treated in Gradient Boosting?

Tags: machine-learning, interaction, boosting, generalized-additive-model

In GAMs interaction terms have to be expressly specified as covariates, even for simple linear relationships. On the contrary, with Gradient boosting this is not nesessary because the algorithm itself does it implicitly by design. This last point is not clear to me.

Hence: how does gradient boosting include interaction terms?

Comment: Gradient boosting fits a GAM. A GAM does not have to be parametric.

Comment: How can you fit a GAM without assuming a distribution?

Comment: In general you do not necessarily assume a distribution when you fit any regression model, just something about the regression function (usually the conditional mean of $Y$ given the covariates $X$, possibly transformed via a link function). If you assume that the additive components that make up the regression function are nonparametric (e.g. regression trees or splines) then the GAM is a nonparametric model.

Comment: This would depend on the method. E.g., You could find out how trees do this. But you'd have to ask about each method separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the specifics will depend on your particular nonparametric method. [Gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) is a meta-method, and it typically uses classification and regression trees (CARTs), so I'll work with that.

An interaction is of the following abstract form:

> The impact of a predictor A on the outcome depends on the value of a different predictor B.

CARTs can easily model this by first splitting on B and then, on lower levels, splitting on A *differently* for low values of B than for high values of B.

If you have enough data, this will indeed happen automatically. Since CARTs consider *all possible interactions* (instead of the user having to explicitly model them), they need much more data to avoid fitting noise, i.e., spurious interactions.

Comment: True, but for every split, the relationship between the predictors will only be linear. How do we then model interactions with other functional forms (say multiplicative)? Do we just represent it as a new predictor?

Comment: Multiplicative interactions will be approximated by locally constant fits. (Or linear ones. It depends on your CART.) Your CART will split each predictor multiple times to get multiple locally constant fits. If you have enough data, you can approximate multiplicative (or any other) relationships arbitrarily closely.